# Atom snippnets not working with TAB trigger

Tags: atom-editor

I have managed to set up a few .scss snippets in Atom. They all work fine, but are not triggered when I press the TAB key. They only work when I press ENTER. When I press the TAB key it will put in a CSS declaration instead of the actual snippet. Also, when I press the ENTER key to get the snippet to appear I cannot TAB through the cursor positions that I have set up in my snippets.

Here is the code I have used:

```html
# --------------------------------- SCSS
'.source.css.scss':
 'breakpoint mobone':
  'prefix': 'mobone'
  'body': """
   @include breakpoint(mobone) {
    $1
   }
   """
 'breakpoint mobone-up':
  'prefix': 'mobone-up'
  'body': """
   @include breakpoint(mobone-up) {
    $1
   }
   """
 'breakpoint mobtwo':
  'prefix': 'mobtwo'
  'body': """
   @include breakpoint(mobtwo) {
    $1
   }
   """
 'breakpoint mobtwo-up':
  'prefix': 'mobtwo-up'
  'body': """
   @include breakpoint(mobtwo-up) {
    $1
   }
   """
 'breakpoint tabone':
  'prefix': 'tabone'
  'body': """
   @include breakpoint(tabone) {
    $1
   }
   """
 'breakpoint tabone-up':
  'prefix': 'tabone-up'
  'body': """
   @include breakpoint(tabone-up) {
    $1
   }
   """
 'breakpoint tabtwo':
  'prefix': 'tabtwo'
  'body': """
   @include breakpoint(tabtwo) {
    $1
   }
   """
 'breakpoint tabtwo-up':
  'prefix': 'tabtwo-up'
  'body': """
   @include breakpoint(tabtwo-up) {
    $1
   }
   """
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Since these snippets work for me, there's probably a conflict with another package. Open the keybinding resolver and trigger any of your snippets with Tab and see what is reported in the bottom of the window.

Alternatively, open Atom in safe mode (`atom --safe`) and see if your snippets work. If they do, there certainly is a conflict.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I opened Atom in safe mode and the snippets worked. What would be the best way to check to see which package is causing the issue?

Comment: If it doesn't get shown in the `keybinding-resolver`, you probably need to go through all your packages that work in the `.source.css.scss` scope.

Comment: Thanks again. I went through and it was emmet that was causing the issue. Once I disabled the package the snippets worked as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is likely a conflict with another package working in the same scope.

1. Open Atom in safe mode `atom --safe` to see if the snippets in `snippets.cson` work.
2. Open the `keybinding-resolver` (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> on Mac, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> elsewhere) and trigger your snippets. In the lower part of your screen, it will show the command (or snippet) that executed.

At worst, you will have to go through all packages that work in the `.source.css.scss` scope (which presumably aren't that many.)